# target HTML 'name' attribute a rails form builder with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, jquery-validate

I've created a multi-step form based off of the tutorial [here](https://djaodjin.com/blog/jquery-multi-step-validation.blog.html). It integrates Jquery Validation in the process to make sure that the data is clean before it hits the server. The validation and multi-step form all work as desired, but since Jquery Validation targets the HTML `name` tags instead of the `id` I had to change them manually in order to get the validation to work.

```
rules: {
                      registrant_first_name: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2,
                    },

                    ...
        },
```

And in the form helper:

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, name: 'registrant_first_name', class: 'form-control' %>
```

Yet, while this works this sends my params out of the registrant controller and I'd need to re-configure the model to accept the new params. The form responds by rejecting the data and saying the fields are blank (which they technically are)

```
registrant_first_name: John
registrant_last_name: Doe
registrant_email: johndoe@msn.com
```

While I'm pretty sure I can fix this problem by simply re-configuring the registrants model to accept the parameters, I'm wondering is there a way to configure the Jquery Validation rules to target the name attribute generated by the forms helper? (currently it throws an error)

```
rules: {
                      registrant[first_name]: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 2,
                    },

                    ...
        },
```

And if not, is there any harm in configuring the model to allow these parameters that will no longer belong to the `registrants` hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm wondering is there a way to configure the Jquery Validation rules to target the name attribute generated by the forms helper? (currently it throws an error)

Yes.  Simply surround the name with quotation marks.

```
rules: {
    'registrant[first_name]': {
        required: true,
        minlength: 2,
        ....
```

[Documentation: **Fields with complex names (brackets, dots)**](https://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/#link-fields-with-complex-names-(brackets-dots)):

> *"If your form consists of fields using names that aren't legal JavaScript identifiers, you have to quote those names when using the `rules` option"*

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly